# Need to assign multiple tables to the parameter "log-output = TABLE" in MySQL 5.5.25

Tags: mysql

Is there is a way to assign multiple tables to the parameter "log-output = TABLE" in my.cnf? I would like to keep rotating the tables, take the backup and truncate the table after rotation.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set multiple table into this parameter. You can set only 'TABLE', 'FILE', 'NONE', or 'TABLE,FILE'.

If you want to store log and then clear log table, then copy data from log table into another table, and after - truncate log table.

[Selecting General Query and Slow Query Log Output Destinations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/log-destinations.html).